# A locally convex space is normable, iff there exists a bounded and open set.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

I want to show, that a locally hausdorff space is seminormable, if and only if there exists a bounded and open set. My proof goes as follows:
Let $B \subset V$ be an open and bounded 0-neighborhood, $V$ a topological vector space and $\mathcal{T}_{  V} $ a topological local base. I claim that
\begin{align}\label{EQ:**}
B\cap \mathcal{T}_{  V}  =\left\{  B\cap U\mid U\in \mathcal{T}_{  V} \right\}  
\end{align} is also a local base, making $V$ a locally bounded TVS.

proof

The inclusion $B\cap U \subset U$ makes $B\cap \mathcal{T}_{  V} $ finer then $\mathcal{T}_{  V}  $. On the other hand, $B\cap U$ is open with respect to $\mathcal{T}_{  V}$ so both topologies are equivalent.

Having shown this, let $B$ be a bounded 0-neighbourhood and $V$ be locally convex. We can assume $B$ to be absolutely convex, since the convex hull, as well as the balanced convex hull stay bounded and that $B$ is absorbing (every 0-neighborhood is). Now setting
$$
\left\|  v \right\|  := \sup\limits_{ B'\in \mathcal{B}} \left\{  \mu _{  B'}  (v)\right\} 
$$
should give the desired norm, where $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{T}_{  V}\cap B $ and $\mu _{  B'}  (v)=\inf\limits_{}\left\{  t\mid v\in tB'\right\}  $ is the Minkowski functional. It is bounded, because of $\mu _{  B'}  (v)\leq \mu _{  B}  (v)$ for all $B'=B\cap U$, $U \in \mathcal{T}_{  V} $.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition you seek to prove is a version of a slightly more general one that is sometimes accredited to Kolmogorov. The more general proposition reads:

> **Proposition**: A real or complex topological vector space is normable if and only if it is Hausdorff and possesses a convex bounded neighborhood of zero.

Dropping the Hausdorff assumption, the proposition remains true if "normable" is replaced by "seminormable".

Your proof seems to be in line with a standard one, except the supremum appearing in definition of the norm. Given that $B$ is a bounded absolutely convex neighborhood of zero, it suffices to consider the Minkowski functional $\mu_{B}$ (in your notation), which is a desired seminorm (or norm if the Hausdorff assumption is imposed).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I even realized that $\mu_{B'}(v)\leq \mu_B(v)$, but it didn't cross my mind to just use this for the definition of the seminorm (or norm in the Hausdorff case). Do you perhaps know some literture, where I can look up that Proposition?

Comment: Most books on topological vector space should have this proposition. One reference I myself use recently is "Topological vector spaces and their applications" by Bogachev and Smolyanov. Check theorem 1.5.7, page 40 in that book [here](https://books.google.dk/books?id=7WUkDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&hl=zh-CN&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false).