# Show this set is unbounded in topological vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(V, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological vector space. A subset $B\subseteq V$ is bounded if for all opens $O$ containing $0$, there is $t > 0$ such that $B \subseteq tO$.

Next, consider the topological vector space $V = C([0,1], \mathbb{R})$ with topology $\mathcal{T}$ the initial topology generated by
$$\{ev_x: C[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}: f \mapsto f(x)\mid x \in [0,1]\}$$

I'm trying to show that if $x \in [0,1]$ and $a < 0 <  b$, then the open

$$U:= \{f\in C[0,1]: a < f(x) <b\}$$

is not bounded, but I was unsuccesful. I tried to argue by contradiction, but got nowhere. Then I tried to prove that there is an open $O$ such that for all $t> 0$ we have

$$U \not\subseteq tO$$

or equivalently

$$1/t U = \{f \in C[0,1]: a/t <f(x) < b/t\}\subseteq O$$
but I struggle to find the open $O$ that makes the argument work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the your topology has a sub-basis of the form $S_{y,c,d}=\{f|ev_y(f)\in (c,d)\}$. So let $y\in [0,1]$, we wish to argue that $U\not\subseteq tS_{y,-1,1}$ for any $t$.

Indeed, assume without loss of generality that $x<y$ and define $g_t$ to be the function
$$
g_t(z)=\begin{cases} 0  & z\in [0,x] \\ 2t \frac{z-x}{y-x} & z\in[x,y] \\ 2t & z\in [y,1]\end{cases}
$$
Then, $g_t$ is clearly continuous for every $t$ and $g_t\in U$, however, $g_t\not \in t S_{y,-1,1}=S_{y,-t,t}$. Thus, $U$ is not bounded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm very confused. You thus found an open bounded neightborhood of 0. But https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3244249/a-locally-convex-space-is-normable-iff-there-exists-a-bounded-and-open-set implies then that this space is normable, and I believe it is well known that this is not the case?

Comment: Your $U$ isn't open. Let $f\in U$ and note, for instance, that any $S_{x,a,b}$ contains a function $g$ such that $|g(y)|\geq 2(|a|+|b|)$ where $y\neq x$.

Comment: Ah... goddamnit, I misread your definition of $U$. Just a sec.

Comment: What do you mean with $y \in x$? You mean $y \in [0,1]$?

Comment: I think you're right $U$ is not open. But it is bounded as you stated originally.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: As written, it is definitely open. I also read $U$ as if $x$ were arbitrary, but it's fixed in the line above.

Comment: So, long story short: $S_{x,a,b}$ is open, but not bounded, whereas $\{f| f([0,1])\subseteq (a,b)\}$ is bounded, but not open.

Comment: OK, for fixed $x$ it is open and not bounded, all $x$ it bounded and not open.

Comment: And everyone agrees. :)

Comment: Hi @WoolierThanThou. I unaccepted because it is unclear to me why $g_t \in U$. We have $g_t(x)=2t$ and this isn't necessarily in $]a,b[$. Also, your answer contains several typo's, for example $g_t$ is undefined at $z=y$ as it stands now. If you are willing to correct these mistakes, I'm more than happy to offer my gratitude and accept the answer again.

Comment: It sure was full of typos. The new piecewise function is equal to $0$ at $x=0$. That should do.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. I forgot about this.